# How can I implement MVVM while just working with FirebaseAuth only for Login/Singup page?

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm trying to write clean and professional code. I'm just a beginner in Android. I'm used to writing a BaseActivity, implement interfaces and separate methods and class. But, I want to learn about MVVM design pattern.

What I tried:
I followed some YouTube tutorials and read some post on medium and google. Everyboady make a demo using Room DB with LiveData. But I don't want to do that level of stuff. I even implemented as well by watching tutorials, but still there are so many things confusing for me.

My question is that isn't it possible to learn slowly and step by step implementing MVVM in our daily life along side with office work?

Let's say, I have to make login / singup page with Firebase auth. and I want to implement MVVM in that. How can I do that?

Kindly advice me, I know I haven't posted any code, but I'm not able to understand that where to start?

You don't need to post code, you can give me link of tutorials and youtube videos if you find helpful for yourself.

Also clear my doubt that is it possible to use MVVM in login/ signup. if yes How? Can you give me a demo with or without any db operation?

Comment: here is firebase auth tutorial hope it help u [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-mvvm-example/)

Comment: @hasanhasan Thanks for suggestion. But that is written in kotlin, I need for Java.

Comment: here is another from [medium](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) .

Comment: @hasanhasan Let me implement by myself first.

Comment: @hasanhasan Can you please help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078980/how-can-i-make-separate-code-on-onchanged-while-observing-with-livedata-in-mvv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excellent open-source project by MindOrks that implements MVVM architecture using Dagger2, Room, RxJava2, FastAndroidNetworking and PlaceholderView

https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture

Comment: Thanks, but this all room, rxjava and all are complex for me. I want very basic example.

Comment: Can you please help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078980/how-can-i-make-separate-code-on-onchanged-while-observing-with-livedata-in-mvv