# How can I make separate code on onChanged() while observing with LiveData in MVVM? [Not solved]

Tags: android, mvvm

So, I implemented

```
public class DriverLoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements Observer<LoginUser>
```

And, onChanged overided.

```
 @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable LoginUser loginUser) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Objects.requireNonNull(loginUser).getEmail())) {
            binding.email.setError("Email Id can't be blank");
            binding.email.requestFocus();
        } else if (!loginUser.isEmailValid()) {
            binding.email.setError("Please enter valid Email Id");
            binding.email.requestFocus();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Objects.requireNonNull(loginUser).getPassword())) {
            binding.password.setError("Password can't be blank");
            binding.password.requestFocus();
        } else if (!loginUser.isPasswordLengthGreaterThan5()) {
            binding.password.setError("Password length must be at least 8 digit");
            binding.password.requestFocus();
        } else {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(loginUser.getEmail(), loginUser.getPassword()).addOnCompleteListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Now, for this activity, I have 2 buttons. so, the depending on the button click, this onChanged will be call. Now I want to do login button for login user and registre for registration. How can I make it separate in onChanged method?

Please suggest me the very best practice.

I don't think I should use setter in viewmodel class and getter in activity. It don't consider MVVM practice. right?

Comment: Though huge, let me try to answer.

Comment: @ChintanSoni waiting desperately

Comment: I wish you could have started with Kotlin as I haven't touched Java since long :)

Comment: @ChintanSoni umm, no. I think I'll convert into java using some online tool.

Comment: Can give link to GitHub repo to this project.

Comment: @hasanhasan wait

Comment: @hasanhasan https://github.com/umangburman/MVVM-DataBinding-With-LiveData-Login

Comment: @hasanhasan I followed this tutorial and after I just implemented  interface globally and also added some more buttons. That's it.

Comment: Ok, i am seeing some mistake like using `ViewModel` package name issue as u aal earlier. Let me have good look .... Currently I. Traveling.

Comment: @hasanhasan just change package name ViewModel to small letter, and remove and reimport. I got exactly same problem, it will work.

Comment: Is there any extra data you are taking to register user?

Comment: @Zaartha As of now email id and pwd. but that will may be add other details. And I'm asking to learn correct methodology even the data is same in both button. you can assume that for the different button I've to completelty different things

Comment: @DipaliSingh Check my answer

Comment: @Zaartha can you please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119161/what-is-extra-in-url-while-working-with-get-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVM, the ViewModel is designed to manage data. The ideal way would be handling your API calls in the ViewModel. Using LiveData for this is not the ideal use of LiveData.

Your ViewModel can have

```
public void onLoginClick(View view) {
    //Implement Login API call here
}


public void onRegisterClick(View view){
    //Implement Register API call here

}
```

And in your activity_main.xml

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> LoginViewModel.onLoginClick()}"

<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:onClick="@{(v) -> LoginViewModel.onRegisterClick()}"
```

Check this 
https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm/ui/login

Comment: Acha, clear me 2-3 things. You want to say that whaterver I want to do on button click, I should do in viewmodel and  not activity? So let's say in my main activity. I have 2 buttons, one for api call and one for open new activity. So what should I do?

Comment: One more doubt. Let's say I have 10 button in my activity. And all buttons logics are completely different from each other. so should I create 10 different methds? and what if after the button click logic I have to show that result in activity?

Comment: To open new activity you need to implement Navigator as mentioned in the example link I posted. Here is the link to the Navigator. Please read that.  https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvvm/ui/login/LoginNavigator.java

Comment: @DipaliSingh Anytime :)